# xlsx download in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, download, concrete5

I have built a website for a client using Concrete5 as the CMS.

There is a download link on [this page](http://matchbusiness.com.au/more/resources/sales-labour-tracking-tool/) which links (via Concrete5's file manager code) to an xlsx file.

If this link is clicked on in Google Chrome or Internet Explorer, the file downloads as expected and everything is A-OK.

If this link is clicked on in Mozilla Firefox, however, the user is instead presented with the raw source of the .xlsx file, and no option to download it.

The headers and content the server is serving appear identical, so I can't understand why the two browsers would behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to edit your .htaccess file and add

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

This will signal to every browser that any doc docx xls and xlsx file from your site ought to be downloaded.

**Edit:**

You could also  the HTML5 download attribute like so:

```
<a href="path/to/file" download>Click here to download</a>
```

This opens a "save as" dialog regardless of file type without taking you away from the page.

Comment: Ripper. Worked! I had to remove the space after xlsx in your regex for it to work, but I can't edit your answer because that's less than 6 characters worth of changes. Thanks! :)